# Finding strings which contain the most 'a' letters

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I've got a question if I can somehow shorten my code - I need to find what strings in my List contain the most 'a' letters. I made it as below, but I'm almost sure that I could do it shorter, but I don't know how.
So first of all I map my list to tuple, where I have `(el, num)` where the `num` is how many the 'a' contains (using foldLeft).
Then I use `maxBy` so I take an element that have the most 'a' letters and then I filter all elements where the `num` == `res2._2` (because there could be more than one element having the same number of 'a' letters, so I can't stop at `maxBy`

My code:

```
 def mostA(l: List[String]): List[String] = {

    val res = l.map( string => (string, string.foldLeft(0)((acc,b) => if (b == 'a') acc + 1 else acc)))
    val res2 = res.maxBy(x => x._2)
    val res3 = res.filter(x => x._2 == res2._2).map{case (str, num) => str}
    res3

  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since your code is already working and you simply want to find a way to improve it, I would suggest asking on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), although be sure to go through their [help pages](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) first.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP's code is working already and it just needs to be made shorter/better. I think this question probably belongs on Code Review SE.

Comment: @user I believe that rather than closing it, you could have migrated it.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Sorry, I don't know how to do that. Can you do that now or would the question have to be reopened?

Comment: @user I just flag it for moderator intervention explaining it should be migrated to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - Sorry for taking too long, I was in the cellphone.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez For future reference; Code Review is not a migration target for Stack Overflow. As Code Review gets too many bad recommendations from Stack Overflow. As such only moderators can migrate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is already pretty small and concise. However, there is a couple of improvements we can do:

```scala
def mostLetter(letter: Char)(data: List[String]): List[String] = {
  val counts = data.map(s => s -> s.count(_ == letter))
  val max = counts.maxBy(_._2)._2
  counts.collect {
    case (str, `max`) => str
  }
}
```

Namely, we replaced the `foldLeft` in the **String** with `count` and we fused together the `filter` + `map` in a single `collect`
Also, remember the last expression is the return thus it is unnecessary to assign it to a variable to later just return it.

Comment: really? So is the max already what is returned? I haven't known it before, I thought I have to return it.
Btw. Why do you use `collect` instead of `filter`?

Comment: @funnyguy not sure what you mean with the max is already returned. - I use `collect` because I need to `filter` and `map` at the same time, look that I `collect` the elements whose `count` is equals to the `max`

Comment: I'm not sure about the performance of this. `data.groupBy(_.count(_ == letter)).maxBy(_._1)._2` feels simpler to me but I have no idea if that's any better, complexity-wise. In any case, I guess it doesn't matter if the OP isn't processing too many strings.

Comment: @user oh that is a pretty cool solution! It should have better performance than mine a similar to the one of Dima. I would suggest you to add that as an answer :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm not totally sure if this question is okay for Stack Overflow, so I'm going to ask the OP to post on Code Review and see if I can answer there.

Answer (score 2):

With a bit of an effort, you can do it in one go:

```
    l.foldLeft(List[String] -> 0) { case ((strs, max), s) => 
       val n = s.count(_ == letter)
       if (n == max) (s::strs, max) else if (n > max) (s::Nil, n) else (strs, max)
    }._1.reverse
```

Comment: You should make sure your code compiles first. There are a few minor mistakes, see [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/rJCLRlMSTnGLLQOiTKVsKA) for a fixed version.

Comment: Fair enough. No one's going to copy code from SO directly without modifying it (they shouldn't, at least), but I still prefer to have a compiler prooofread my code. To each their own, I guess.